# Tabular model issue

Tags: ssas-tabular

The below is my tabular model, both are dimension tables. However, I am not able to filter the policies on Effective year from PolicyEffective date table when trying to browse the data in the pivot table.

Comment: Hello! It seems that some detail or images are missing from your post.

Comment: I have 2 dimensions Policy and PolicyEffectiveDate(date dimension). They both have Effectivedate field in them. I am connecting these tables together using EffectiveDate field. And I tried to browse the design. I wanted to see the Policies for a particular Effective year. However when I pull PolicyNo's from Policy dim and EffYear from PolicyEffectiveDate, I am seeing all Years specified under each PolicyNo. What I want is Policies for Effective Year say 2016.

Comment: Can you post a picture, with relationships, of your model? Please note the arrows on the relationship; it shows the direction of the 'data flow'. If the arrow points from Policy to PolicyEffectiveDate, the Policy table doesn't get filtered when slicing from the PolicyEffectiveDate table.